# AudioKit Custom directory for processed AKAudioFile

Tags: swift, macos, audiokit

Can't figure out how i can choose another output directory for such methods like:

extractAsynchronously,
exportAsynchronously,
reverseAsynchronously

Is it possible?

An app produces huge amount of temporary files and i just want to create separate directory for all temp files and clean it after work is done.

Answer (score 0):

All of those take a baseDir BaseDirectory argument.  One idea is that if you choose .custom, the directory will be the same as the input file.  Then you could clean out both input and output files together.

If you don't want to do that you could extend AKAudioFile with a new location, perhaps calling it "output" and then do what you need there.

Comment: Sorry, how i can extend AKAudioFile that way?